# Can I get table name from source path in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF pipeline with an ODATA source.

I'm copying that into an SQL database using autocreate table.
I would like to autogenerate the table name as well, but I can't figure out how it's done.

The name I would like to use is the Path name from the source:
[image]

It should somehow be used as the table name:

[image]

Is this possible in ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I get table name from source path in ADF?

**we cant access dataset name in pipeline to work around this we can get dataset name by creating parameter**

To get Source table name in sink first we have to create parameter or variable in pipeline with name tablename and type string.

[image]

Then create parameter in source dataset as table name with type string.

[image]

Then in the path add dynamic value `@dataset().tablename` to get value of parameter created in above step.

[image]

In dataset properties add dynamic value for table name `@pipeline().parameters.tablename` to get value from pipeline parameter and pass this value to source dataset.

[image]

Then create parameter in sink dataset as table name with type string.

[image]

Then in the schema name add `dbo` and in tablename add dynamic value `@dataset().tablename` to get value of parameter created in above step.

[image]

In dataset properties add dynamic value for table name `@pipeline().parameters.tablename` to get value from pipeline parameter and pass this value to sink dataset.

[image]

**Successfully copied table with same name from ODATA source to SQL database.**

[image]

**Note: I have table name Airlines in my ODATA source.**