# Can I get all tables dynamically from Odata source to azure SQL server using data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can get multiple tables from Odata source using azure data factory?

Can I get multiple tables from Odata source?

[image]

[image: how can i take pathname dynamically]

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: I can get error. 'Type=System.NullReferenceException,Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object., Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,'

Comment: Try to provide what you have tried so far? like images of pipeline?

Comment: How can I take parameters Default value?

Comment: AFAIK, it might not be possible to get multiple tables at the same for OData dataset. If you want to use multiple tables you can use a ForEach. First get the list of tables and pass it to ForEach. In the OData dataset, edit the path and use a dataset parameter in it. Give the item value(table name) to that parameter in the copy activity inside ForEach.

Comment: how to do mapping, and how can set item value,

Comment: you want to copy multiple tables from OData to multiple tables in SQL or single table in SQL?

Comment: multiple tables in SQL

Comment: Any updates, please give me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below method only works when you have list of tables that you want to copy from Odata source.

Here I have given the sample demonstration using SQL dataset as source. You can follow the same for your OData dataset.

First create a dataset parameter for the table name.

[image]

Now, go to your OData dataset and click on edit in Path. In dynamic content give parameter `@dataset().source_table_name`.

[image]

Do the same for sink dataset also.

Here, I have taken list of table names in an array parameter.

[image]

Give this to ForEach activity and check on Sequential in it.

Inside ForEach use copy activity. You can give the `@item()` value to the dataset parameter in source like below.

[image]

Do the same in sink of copy activity and make sure you check on **Auto create table** in the **Table options** in it.

By this way you can copy multiple tables from your source to SQL database.

Comment: I want OData tables, that tables path is different, can i share OData source url for better understanding

Comment: I think for both SQL db and Odata datasets, the table path is same. You can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73740623/can-i-get-table-name-from-source-path-in-adf/73743102#73743102) to know how to give table path dynamically using dataset parameters.

Comment: SQL and Odata table path is different, im sharing a sample Odata url. https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/